# Copying table cells to clipboard without input tags - Javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, clipboard

I have this simple function that allows you to click any table cell and it copies the data to the clipboard.  The cell will also blink red to let you know it was copied. This works fine, but you'll notice there's an input tag in each cell (all the similar examples I found also used inputs or some other form tags) I don't need inputs because the data in my cells isn't going to change.  Is there a way to do this without input tags.  Would the data in a normal table cell be `innerHTML` Can that be copied onclick? No jQuery please.

```js
function myFunction(itemid) {
  var copyText = document.getElementById(itemid);
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  // blink red
  document.getElementById(itemid).style.backgroundColor="#FF0000";
  setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(itemid).style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF";},300);
}
```

```css
::selection {background:none;}
input {outline:0;cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<table>
<td><input type="text" value="Cheese" id="cell1" onclick="myFunction('cell1')"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="Crackers" id="cell2" onclick="myFunction('cell2')"></td><tr>

<td><input type="text" value="Milk" id="cell3" onclick="myFunction('cell3')"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="Bread" id="cell4" onclick="myFunction('cell4')"></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, the animation is up to you

```
        let table = document.getElementById('tableId');

    table.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let target = e.target;
        if(target.localName === 'td') {
            let range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(target);  
            let sel= document.getSelection(); 
            sel.removeAllRanges(); 
            sel.addRange(range); 

            document.execCommand('copy');
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            target.classList.add('copy-animate');
            setTimeout(() => {
                target.classList.remove('copy-animate');
            }, 200);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working, what am I doing wrong.  I'm not experienced with javascript....  here's the code...

Comment: Ooops, I'm not sure how to show my code in a comment

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Did you add the table element an id=tableId ?

Comment: Yeah, I did that.  I'm sure I'm doing something stupid.   Hold on, I'll add mine to your code post...

Comment: The error means document.getelementbyid is returning a null

Comment: GOT IT!   The script needs to be at the end, not in the head, thank you!

Comment: @CheeseFlavored You can add your code as an update at the end of your question.

Comment: I could use help with one more thing.  I just realized there's a few cells in my table that I don't want this feature to work on.  I was thinking I could add a class to those cells called nocopy.  And anytime a cell had that class this feature would be ignored.  I assume it would involve altering this line, something like  `if(target.localName === 'td' && class !='nocopy')`

Comment: I figured it out.  I added `&& target.className !='nocopy'`